# In Flutter, does a ListView Builder inside a SingleChildScrollView still lazily load?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, singlechildscrollview

In Flutter I have a SingleChildScrollView with a column as the child. Inside that column is 3 widgets: A ListView.separated widget, a sized box, and a different ListView.separated widget.

The ListView.separated widgets have shrinkWrap set to true and physics set to NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() to allow the SingleChildScrollView to handle scrolling.

My question is, are the two ListView widgets loaded lazily (on demand) or does the SingleChildScrollView and column parent mean they are loaded in full when the page loads?

Answer (score 0):

As per My Understanding ,The Size Would have been Assigned to the Page At LoadTime, or When The Builder Runs, So Single Child Scroll View Just Assumes It have Fixed Height or Width, Rest the ListView Behaves as Usual.

Answer (score 0):

*are the two ListView widgets loaded lazily (on demand)?*

the answer is **NO**. this is what the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) said:

> so that the lazy instantiation of a sliver-based ListView or
> CustomScrollView is not expected to provide any performance benefit.

---

more explanation TL;DR

its not recommend to wrap `ListView` inside `SingleChildScrollView`,  **except your `ListView` expected to fit on the screen**.

#### SingleChildScrollView :

> This widget is useful when you have a single box that will normally be
> entirely visible

---

> If the viewport is expected to usually contain content beyond the
> dimensions of the screen, then SingleChildScrollView would be very
> expensive.

it recommends using the `SingleChildScrollView` when the child has finite height (around screen height).

When you have 2 or more `ListView.separated` widget that has big dimensions, it would be better to wrap with `ListView`. Do not using `SingleChildScrollView`.